# Why do I need to use @Text to display a date field?

Tags: xpages

I have a computed field with the following formula.

```
var time = "";
if(@IsNewDoc()==1) time = @Now();
else time = @Text(@GetField("FormCreated"));
return time;
```

The only wy I could get this to work is to wrap the @GetField("FormCreated") with @Text.   The computed field is set as DateTime and FormCreated is an actual date/time value in the document.

Why does @Now not need @Text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use @GetField you will get a NotesDateTime and @Now returns a java date.
try this code

```
var time = "";
if(@IsNewDoc()==1){
 time = @Now();
}else{
var time2:NotesDateTime = @GetField("FormCreated")[0];
time=time2.toJavaDate();
}
return time;
```

Updated the code and added [0] at the end of the @GetField row to get the first entry from the returned vector.

Comment: This has nothing to do with type conversion, but I'm glad to see the curly braces in Fredrik's answer. Code should never contain meaningful whitespace.

Comment: Well Tim, conversion or not my code still works after I edited it because @GetField returns a vector, I missed that but I was writing from memory and not from designer.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. Mostly I was referring to the code in the question, which doesn't have curlies, and is therefore comparatively brittle.

Comment: Bruce, it does work... until anything causes the whitespace to change (e.g. automatic formatting by Designer). If you always include curly braces in your ifs, then your code will not suddenly break if the whitespace changes. That was the only point I was trying to make in this thread: spending a fraction of a second up front to make your code less brittle can prevent hours of confused troubleshooting later on.